# Mounting multiple controllers in Silex

Tags: php, silex

I am trying to have several controllers with multiple mount points. The code us as below

**GearmanController.php**

```
use Silex\Application;

class GearmanController implements \Silex\ControllerProviderInterface
{
    public function connect(Application $app) {

        $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];
        $controllers->get('/info', function() use ($app){

            error_log("gearman prcoesses has ben called");
            return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response('gearman prcoesses has ben called');
        });

        return $controllers;
    }

    public function boot(Application $app)
    {
        // TODO: Implement boot() method.
    }

}
```

**SupervisorController**

```
<?php

use Silex\ControllerProviderInterface;
use Silex\Application;

class SupervisorController implements ControllerProviderInterface
{
    public function connect(Application $app) {

        $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];
        $controllers->get('/processes', function() use ($app){

            error_log("supervisor prcoesses has ben called");
            return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response('gearman prcoesses has ben called');
        });

        return $controllers;
    }

    public function boot(Application $app)
    {
        // TODO: Implement boot() method.
    }
}
```

**bootstrap.php**

```
<?php

    require_once __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";

?>
```

**routes.php**

```
<?php

$app->mount('/supervisor', new SupervisorController());

$app->mount('/gearman', new GearmanController());

?>
```

and the `index.php`

```
<?php

    $app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../app/app.php';

    $app->run();

?>
```

**app.php**

```
<?php

    require_once __DIR__ . '/bootstrap.php';

    $app = new Silex\Application();

    require_once __DIR__ . '/../src/routes.php';

    return $app;

?>
```

It seems quite simple, but when I hit the url with

```
/gearman/info 
/supervisor/processes
```

I get a `404 Not Found` and nothing is printed in php error logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have error in controller providers. Add routes to controller collection, not application. And return response in actions.

```
public function connect(Application $app)
{
    $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];

    $controllers->get('/info', function() use ($app){
        error_log("gearman prcoesses has ben called");
        return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response('gearman prcoesses has ben called');
    });

    return $controllers;
}
```

Also forward all 404 requests to index.php. Make `.htaccess` config for this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I changed it as you suggested, but still doesn't work.

Comment: also try to change paths to `/info` and `/processes`

Comment: I just get a `404 Not Found`. I am hitting the url `http://vhost-path_to_index.php/supervisor/processes`

Comment: `$controllers->get('/info'...`, `$controllers->get('/processes'...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104028/discussion-between-user3288346-and-max-p).